# Compiling on different machines delivers different hex files of Arduino ESP8266 project

Tags: c++, gcc, arduino, esp8266

I am developing a ESP8266 application using the [Arduino core for ESP8266](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino). After compiling the project on different machines I noticed a large difference at both *.bin files.

I reproduced this behaviour with an empty project. The result after compilation was:

**Device 1:**

> Program Sketch1 size: 221.999 bytes (used 21% of a 1.044.464 byte
>   maximum) (0,97 secs) Minimum Memory Usage: 31564 bytes (39% of a 81920
>   byte maximum)

**Device 2:**

> Program Sketch1 size: 221.995 bytes (used 21% of a 1.044.464 byte
>   maximum) (0,63 secs) Minimum Memory Usage: 31568 bytes (39% of a 81920
>   byte maximum)

Comparing the *.bin files with a hex editor showed large differences. **I assume that compiling the same application on different devices should produce exactly the same file.**

- I activated the *show build properties* and the *verbose* function of
  the compiler and compared the output. Excepting the paths there is
  no difference.
- I compared the whole ESP8266 libary using WinMerge. The result is, there is absolutely no difference.

I can not detect a single difference between the machines. Is there a way a compiler can produce different files on different machines, or what could be the problem?

**EDIT:**
I found the reason of the 4 byte difference: The compiler compiles the path of the ESP8266 libary in the *.bin file 4 times. Since the windows usernames are different (1 char length difference), 4 bytes are added up. This explains the different file sizes but not the differences inside the files.

To show you the differences I uploaded the files:

- [Machine 1](https://www.file-upload.net/download-12373219/Sketch11.bin.html)
- [Machine 2](https://www.file-upload.net/download-12373222/Sketch12.bin.html)

The files are showing multiple differences. Note this is an empty project, a more complex project is showing much more differences.

So to bring it to the point: **Why are there differences inside the compiled *.bin files?**

Comment: Padding? Is there a sample of the differences? Is there a point where they are the same and then deviate?

Comment: I've edited my question and added some more information @FrankC.

Comment: what's the problem?

Comment: @dandavis Why are there differences inside the compiled *.bin files?

Comment: no, i mean the actual problem said differences are causing you; that's not clear... The compiler uses everything from paths to java versions to determine output, so minor diffs should not cause issues...

Comment: Currently I can not detect any issues - but I am confused an not sure how to deal with the different files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been asked and answered before.  There is no reason to assume, even with as you say an empty project that you will get the same binary each time from compiled code.  One would hope on the same machine the same day same exact source code, etc.  But some compilers add a date/time stamp to the file so even there you might have some difference.  As far as the machine code though there is more than one way to produce functional code that matches the high level language, and the same compiler with different options or different compilers or different versions of the same compiler or even different system libraries used by the same compiler can produce different results.

The general expectation that the same source code produces the same binary is the problem, the expectation.  What you should expect is that the compiler produces code that functionally matches your source code.

Also you are examining the "binary" which includes debug information and other items, only some percentage of that is the machine code that matters, the rest is for disassembly or debugging or loading/programming, etc.  In addition to the machine code not having to match, the extra stuff  doesnt have to match either, not uncommon for a shared system library to be used to create that binary file (the unix way), so you could have the "exact same" compiler and source code but a different update to the same version of your operating system and still get different results if you examine the "binary".

Hopefully not a practice anymore but back in the turbo/borland compiler days one of the compilers would pad structures with whatever was in memory.  so say you were working on some big program it was in ram, you close the editor for some reason, later you compile a program they need 256 bytes for the structure/string but you only initialized 200, the other 56 bytes would be whatever was left in ram, they wouldnt zero it out first, so not only does random stuff from prior runs end up in the "binary", each time you compile that random stuff may or may not be the same even if the machine code and everything else matched.  Again hopefully not a practice today, generally they zero out the padding, but it has happened in the past with commercial pay-for compilers.

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming that the code is well defined, since for code with undefined behaviour the compiler may behave however it pleases.

Even though it is undesirable it is not uncommon for a compiler to produce different, but hopefully functionally equivalent, code on different machines or even on different invocations on the same machine.

When compiling a given program there are often a number of arbitrary choices and unless the compiler programmer takes extreme care it is easy to construct a compiler that makes these choices based on things that change between executions, such as the address of elements in internal datastructures. To add to the problem this aspect of the compiler may not be as frequently tested as the correctness. Often people don't care that the compiler is indeterministic as long as the code is correct.